How to get accounts from solana
I'm a freshman in Solana and I can't find any structured information on "how to"
So my goal is to create a wallet parser to find wallets by criteria(basically whales), I tried to use next RPC-s to use getProgramAccounts, but none of those works:
https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/
quicknode
I see the reason, it's restricted, but I can't find "why" this is happening and I'm frustrated because I see no possibility of using the existing endpoint and if it's the right one.
I'm writing a Python script to get an idea of how it works and currently I have this:
import base64
from typing import List, Union
from httpx import Client as HttpxClient
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.rpc.types import MemcmpOpts
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey


def main():
    client = Client("")

    PUBKEY = ""

    MINT_ADDRESS = ""
    
    pubkey = Pubkey.from_string(PUBKEY)
    mint_address = MINT_ADDRESS

    memcmp_opts = MemcmpOpts(offset=4, bytes=mint_address)
    filters: List[Union[int, MemcmpOpts]] = [17, memcmp_opts]

    result = client.get_account_info(pubkey)
    account = result.value.default()
    print(account)
    # Query the program accounts
    # result = client.get_program_accounts(pubkey)
    #
    # # Print the result (to debug and check the output)
    # print(result.value)
    #
    # # You can also check the total number of results
    # print(f"Total number of accounts found: {len(result.value)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Also, where I can find those Mints and pubkeys? Currently I'm getting them from chatgtp :DD

getProgramAccounts is a very resource-intensive operation, so you will probably get access to it only on a higher priced RPC node.

@AnishMukherjee, how can I achieve my goal then, could you advise?

Like i said, a higher priced RPC node than your current plan. You can get in touch with quiknode support and ask them from which tier they provide access to getProgramAccounts .
